# Laravel model with multiple where condition getting unclear data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello everyone i  want to ask about my problem. I want to get which data if column **a** is **b** or column **b** is **a** for a messaging app. I think you will understand when you see the code. And I also think I did nothing wrong in writing the code. this is my code and the response

Variable for this test

```
var uid: "QqAIR5Qwd6erFQIgSG"
var friend_uid: "Pk6R56XmWMywcObV3a"
```

**Test 1**

```
Chat::where(['sender'=>$request->uid, 'receiver'=>$request->friend_uid])->get();
```

**Response**

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "sender": "QqAIR5Qwd6erFQIgSG",
        "receiver": "Pk6R56XmWMywcObV3a",
        "message": "eyJpdiI6Ik8xSld4QlQ3bmMxaWxBMVlua3B0WXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidGMvNGpXVmowVDczRUhSdGM0UkFQNHNjSVVZcFEyeFJlRThWNGdhMWZQMUFodkIwNWJtNmg4cmg1T2NOTm5ZdXBkdzdWWWhUY3hDQUtnVFBGcHllMkE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjRkYTI5OTk3ZTRhMDAwZTdkYzgwODVmOTgyYzdlYTY2NDg0ZGM2YmExMDVkYzdiMzRhOTliYjA2MjU1ZTc3ZTkiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==",
        "created_at": "2022-03-02T09:29:44.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-02T09:29:44.000000Z"
    }
]
```

This is valid response

**Test 2**

```
Chat::where(['sender'=>$request->friend_uid, 'receiver'=>$request->uid])->get();
```

**Response**

```
"data": []
```

This is valid because it doesn't exist in the database, if there is then he will appear I've tried it.

**Test 3** (i want to do this)

```
Chat::where(['sender'=>$request->uid, 'receiver'=>$request->friend_uid])->orWhere('sender'=>$request->friend_uid, 'receiver'=>$request->uid)->get();
```

**Response**

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "sender": "30B67S1tV7O7sJRG2l",
        "receiver": "QqAIR5Qwd6erFQIgSG",
        "message": "eyJpdiI6IkFDaFNMNjZESk96ZU5rSTQyMVhOUEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaDZyZU9TRSs2c0VTdkVlU2ZDd2JvZHpvQTh3KzZIYjk0NWJrbm90Tk9WREhBV2lrTS9xQW9KOXIza0MwaHUyMGUrTnlBS21aNXBRd1BweXJldlhiOWkzR0hqeHlFWERpdXczZ1E4NTJCSUU9IiwibWFjIjoiMzA3YmQwZmM4NjFlOTk3YmQwNzMwMzgxMTQ4ZmRhZDBhY2IzOWJkZWMzYWVhZmQyNjQ2NGI1MzM4NDQ2ZWY4YiIsInRhZyI6IiJ9",
        "created_at": "2022-03-02T09:29:44.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-02T09:29:44.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "sender": "QqAIR5Qwd6erFQIgSG",
        "receiver": "Pk6R56XmWMywcObV3a",
        "message": "eyJpdiI6Ik8xSld4QlQ3bmMxaWxBMVlua3B0WXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidGMvNGpXVmowVDczRUhSdGM0UkFQNHNjSVVZcFEyeFJlRThWNGdhMWZQMUFodkIwNWJtNmg4cmg1T2NOTm5ZdXBkdzdWWWhUY3hDQUtnVFBGcHllMkE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjRkYTI5OTk3ZTRhMDAwZTdkYzgwODVmOTgyYzdlYTY2NDg0ZGM2YmExMDVkYzdiMzRhOTliYjA2MjU1ZTc3ZTkiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==",
        "created_at": "2022-03-02T09:29:44.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-02T09:29:44.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 87,
        "sender": "chT9eSJ0N6HAXlkUUL",
        "receiver": "QqAIR5Qwd6erFQIgSG",
        "message": "eyJpdiI6Ikd4ZFZZTE1IVXRGQXNCVmUxUmJhcUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNWNUZE91Mk41K2o5Si9TSktOdEpNVSswYlVXZDlQd2hyTWY0d256cEJ4YkZKNVg0Y2hwbmNiUTJkZFhMSGxzVSIsIm1hYyI6IjA5ZDk2MDNkYzFhYzY0MTNlNTM3ODNmZDFiZDU3OTc2NThkODg4MGQzZGM5ZWQyYWRjM2Q1YzJmODkwNmUwOTYiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==",
        "created_at": "2022-03-02T09:29:44.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-02T09:29:44.000000Z"
    }
]
```

why when I try with a query like this I get data which doesn't match the uid or friend_uid? what happened and if where is the error in my program?, please help, thank you.

**SOLVED BY RUN php artisan migrate:refresh**

Answer (score 1):

That is very odd. I could not see any issues in your code. If you can't find a fix and just want to get it over with using a quick solution, simply merge the two working collections you have created:

```
$test1 = Chat::where(['sender'=>$request->uid, 'receiver'=>$request->friend_uid])->get();
$test2 = Chat::where(['sender'=>$request->friend_uid, 'receiver'=>$request->uid])->get();
$test3 = $test1->merge($test2);
```

Not very clean, I know, but it's an okay solution if you can't solve the problem from its root.

Comment: Thank you for you response!. and thank you for the solution it will work.

Comment: i tried to php artisan migrate:refresh and it can. That means there was a bug in the database.:)

Comment: Glad you found it this easily. Those bugs usually hurt the longer they take to find because of how silly they are. I recommend keeping a note somewhere with all the commands that you use and noting what scenarios you needed them for. 

And of course, be sure to use my favorite command `php artisan optimize:clear` whenever your site is acting up and you have doubts that it is caching something. It's an all-around cache clearing command.

Comment: @gawl yeah wkwkw.. thankk youu sirr, i will do it